# Pushing new observables based on input from previous in RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I'm finding it difficult to compose an subject or observable where I have validation. This is the nature of Functional programming, but it seems that Reactive Programming only takes care of each piece of data. Also, the examples are a bit too generalistic, no real world example that covers a lot of aspects, though this is a personal opinion.

I'd like to send another value to the observer based on the previous one, but I can't find out how to achieve this.

```
 Rx.Observable.create( function(obs) {
  obs.next(1)
  // if value is one, compile 3, if not, respond with 2
  obs.next(someVal)
  obs.onCompleted()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd find it simpler to use subject and map:

```
let src = new Subject<number>();
let other = src.map(v => (v === 1 ? 3 : 2));

other.subscribe(v => console.log(v));

src.next(1);// prints 3
src.next(4);// prints 2
```

Comment: Do you know if there's any push-based method I could use? For instance, I would push another observer value to src.next based on the previous

Comment: That's exactly what the map do, it takes one observable and returns a new one that is 'pushed' with values from the original one

Comment: Solved my question partially, but I wonder if there's any way to push a new number to src.next based on the number. Do you know how that is possible?

Comment: That's what the `.map()` does. It pushes to `other` based on the values of src. Do you mean conditionally push in the sense of ignore some values?

Comment: Yes, that was the intention!

Comment: So you can user `.filter()` either alone or combined with the `.map()`